# Can writing to a file while running foreach in R cause connection errors?

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I'm fitting models to about 1000 different time series data parallely. The code seems to be running in some machines but not in others. The error I'm getting (in some cases) is:

```
Error in { : task 135 failed - “cannot open the connection”
```

The task # differs from time to time. Here's a sample of my foreach code:

```
   parallel_df <- foreach(sku = SKUList, .packages = loadedNamespaces(), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {   

    #This prints out the status of the operation in a file
    #So that you can check how deep into the SKUList the code is
    #See "Status.txt"

    writeLines(paste("Training Until: ", dt, "\nFitting for: ", sku, "\nKey", match(sku,SKUList), "of", length(SKUList), "keys"), con = "Status.txt")
# Other things the loop does
}
```

My question is: could it be the case that the connection error is caused by this exact same line? (`writeLines`). I'm guessing that could be the issue because that is the only line in the entire loop that uses an external connection (i.e., a text file to which the code writes the status).

If so, why does this pose problems in certain machines and not in others? It works fine on my personal laptop, but not on other work machines.

Comment: Is it a Unix-only thing? Meaning it does not work on Windows. How do you register cores before foreach?

Comment: No, they are both Windows machines. One of them is a work machine which doesn't provide administration access to the user, while the other (where it works) is a personal machine. I register cores this way: `doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores() - 1)`